# Build modular html file with webpack

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I need to create modular html file with webpack
I want this to be more simple possible

I have main file (index.html) and i need to include some other html file in this file

```
    index.html
         file1.html
         file2.html
```

Here is my webpack config

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var text = require('./src/text.js');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/index.html',
    text: text
  })]
};
```

Here is my index.html file

```
<header>
  <a>
    <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.text.TITLE %>
  </a>
  <div><--- I NEED TO INCLUDE FILE1.HTML HERE---></div>
  <div><--- I NEED TO INCLUDE FILE2.HTML HERE---></div>
</header>
```

What is the best way to achieve this and include all my files ? 
There is better way to make templating syntax to write title, i don't like templating syntax ?
I have also some template variable in my file1.html but the HtmlWebpackPlugin  doesn't convert it , do you know how to do that ?

PS: index.js file is empty

Thanks for you help